# Android arranging layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-xml

Well basically I'm making an app which needs something like an action bar, 4 buttons bellow that and a listview on the rest of the screen. But I'm stuck at how to arrange them, since I'm also using a navigation drawer.

This is how it's supossed to look: [image: lookalikeApp]

The problem is that I have no idea how to arrange them properly I did this but I know it's wrong and it's still missing the actionbar like header:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFormatos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/b_formato"
            android:onClick="formatos"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
             />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTiendas"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/b_tiendas"
            android:onClick="tiendas"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
             />
         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMarcas"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/b_marcas"
            android:onClick="marcas"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
             />

          <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGiros"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/b_categorias"
            android:onClick="categorias"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
             />

          <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOrdenar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/b_ordenar"
            android:onClick="ordenar"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
             />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:translationY="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Not to mention that with translateY on my listView when I get to the bottom of the list I can't see the last item.

I know I'm supossed to be using fragments and I'm looking into that but that won't solve my initial problem so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your xml file as per code below

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/menu"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="70dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnFormatos"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_formato"
                    android:onClick="formatos"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                     />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnTiendas"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_tiendas"
                    android:onClick="tiendas"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                     />
                 <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnMarcas"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_marcas"
                    android:onClick="marcas"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                     />

                  <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnGiros"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_categorias"
                    android:onClick="categorias"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                     />

                  <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnOrdenar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_ordenar"
                    android:onClick="ordenar"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                     />
           </LinearLayout>

           <ListView
               android:id="@+id/list"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:divider="#b5b5b5"
               android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
               android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
               android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               />

       </FrameLayout>


            <ListView
             android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
             android:layout_width="240dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="start"
             android:background="#111"
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
             android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Try and enjoy.

Comment: Wow! Well that was easy lol and there you have me trying with Relative Layouts and more stuff. Thanks a lot works like a charm!